# Liferay how to call a new view

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have the following situation.

I have a portlet who is only available in the control panel and I would like to add a link to another view that comes with the same portlet.

I tried the following:

My jsp's are stored in /admin/* and contains two files:

- view.jsp
- search.jsp

The view.jsp contains the following snippet:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="showSearch" var="showSearchURL" />
<aui:a href="${showSearchURL}" title="Search User" />
```

I added in my portletclass (extends MVCportlet)

```
 public void showSearch(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException{
        //how to call search.jsp?
    }
```

Like the commented line says I would like to show the user a search form. But for some reason I can't find documentation on how to do this in combination with an MVCPortlet.

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
public void showSearch(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws IOException, PortletException{
    // do your action processing, then
    response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", "/admin/search.jsp");
}
```

Better however, if you just want to link to the page from any other jsp within your portlet (like you describe above), there's no need to go through an action - just do this on your linking jsp:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="searchURL">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/admin/search.jsp"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<a href="<%=searchURL%>">Search</a>
```